# Finding the highest occurrence of an item using the 'find' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, find, filtering

I have a model setup where an Artist has many Genres through Albums. I'm trying to get the genre that appears the most from all the albums that belong to the artist.

I've managed to accomplish this using the `group()`, `sort()`, and `limit()` methods but since I only need just one genre I thought a more succinct way to do this would be to use `find()`. What would be the best way to convert what I have now?

```
class Artists < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_many :genres, through: :albums

  def common genre
    genres.group("genres.id").order("count(genres.id) DESC").limit(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: `find` is for lookup using one/multiple columns. But your ask is more than that!

Comment: @emaillenin In that case does the way I have it setup now suffice? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: whatever you have done is already the most efficient way to find the highest occurrence. If you want to make it event more efficient, cache it on the artists table

Comment: How would you cache that value in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` won't work for what you have.

The only slightly more idiomatic way to do what you have is to use `.first` instead of `.limit(1)`, ie.

```
genres.group("genres.id").order("count(genres.id) DESC").first
```

[edited after comment from OP]

Comment: Not sure if this is because I have a HABTM association between my artists and albums but I got this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT  "genres".* FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "albums" ON "genres"."id" = "albums"."genre_id" INNER JOIN "albums_artists" ON "albums"."id" = "albums_artists"."album_id" WHERE "albums_artists"."artist_id" = ? GROUP BY id  ORDER BY count(genres.id) DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Oh, you're right - sorry - I forgot it was a `:through`

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the top genre for each artist:

- New column in artists table - `top_genre`
- after_create (and after_save) callback for album, update the top_genre for the current album's artist

Then you just use the top_genre attribute instead of the group_by and count query.